# Change label in Google contacts

Tags: google-api, google-people-api

I want to synchronize contacts in my application with Google contacts. But not all of them, just those with the right label (tag). I'm using Google's People Apis for this. But I ran into a problem, the memberships property/field which holds informations about labels is read only. I can't even create a contact/person with the right label. It throws an error. Is there a way how to update or create a contact with label?

For mor information head [here](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people).

EDIT:
I've tried both creating and updating a contact. Sending a POST and PATCH request message on https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people:createContact (similiar to update contact). Both fail with the same error, memberships parameter is read-only.

contactGroupId is the id of the label I'm trying to assaign to the contact.

Request body:

```
{
  "memberships": [
    {
      "contactGroupMembership": {
        "contactGroupId": "45asd3d7321gd"
      }
    }
  ]
  ... //Other parameters
}
```

Comment: Could you please share what you've already tried?

Comment: @Chris I've eddited what I've tried. Basically creating or updating a contact with memberships doesn't work. And I haven't seen anywhere any other way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [contactGroups.members.modify](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/contactGroups.members/modify) api call